# com.google.apps.framework.request.NotFoundException: No DesignTimeAgent found for project

Tags: php, dialogflow-cx

I've been struggling to find out why the above error is thrown. I've read and tried all the solutions on google but the problem persists. This code snippet throws an error in the line:

```
$response = $sessionsClient->detectIntent($session, $queryInput);
```

Thank you for looking into this.

```
<?php
//namespace Google\Cloud\Samples\Auth;
namespace Google\Cloud\Dialogflow;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Dialogflow\V2\EntityTypesClient;

use Google\Cloud\Dialogflow\V2\SessionsClient;
use Google\Cloud\Dialogflow\V2\TextInput;
use Google\Cloud\Dialogflow\V2\QueryInput;

$keyfile = "/var/www/html/newestproject-329521-ffa8cd057f77.json";
$projectId = 'newestproject-329521';

detect_intent_texts($projectId, "hi", "12345", $keyfile);

function detect_intent_texts($projectId, $text, $sessionId, $keyfile, $languageCode = 'en-US')
{
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . $keyfile); //your path to file of cred
    // new session
    $test = array('credentials' => $keyfile, 'api_endpoint' => 'europe-west1-dialogflow.googleapis.com:443');
    $sessionsClient = new SessionsClient($test);

    $session = $sessionsClient->sessionName($projectId, $sessionId ?: uniqid());

    printf('Session path: %s' . PHP_EOL, $session);
echo "h3";

    // create text input
    $textInput = new TextInput();
    $textInput->setText($text);
    $textInput->setLanguageCode($languageCode);
echo "h4";

    // create query input
    $queryInput = new QueryInput();
    $queryInput->setText($textInput);
echo "h5"; 
    // get response and relevant info
    $response = $sessionsClient->detectIntent($session, $queryInput);

    $sessionsClient->close();
}
```

Comment: The above error message was caused by the use of an incorrect PROJECT_ID because you haven't linked your Dialogflow agent to the GCP project which you are trying to access. You try to create a new agent with the same PROJECT_ID. Refer to this similar issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-java-client-v2/issues/33#issuecomment-518715852) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64474972/no-designtimeagent-found-when-testing-with-detectintent-api-using-prebuilt-agent).

Comment: @Moreten, Does the above comment resolve your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't , but thanks for your suggestion. Do you see other solutions or causes for this error? A lot of people reported this error as you will se from googling. Do you ownn a working agent zip to share with others who experience this error?

Comment: Hi @Morten, Yes, I think you might have tried to change the location of the agent. Changing the location doesn't change unless the agent is recreated, this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/region) states that once an agent is created, its location cannot change. In order to change an agent's location, you must export and restore to a new agent with a different location. So, I suggest you try to export the agent and start again by creating a new agent, this time please make sure you are selecting the correct region and project ID.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive assistance in solving this problem. I know it sounds arrogant but Google should fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be multiple reasons for the error message. They are as follows:

- Your agent might not be linked to your project ID which you are accessing. Refer to this similar issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-java-client-v2/issues/33#issuecomment-518715852) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64474972/no-designtimeagent-found-when-testing-with-detectintent-api-using-prebuilt-agent).
- If you have tried to change the location of the agent, I would suggest you export the agent first and then start again by creating a new agent, this time please make sure you are selecting the correct region and project ID. Because, the existing agent’s location doesn't change unless the agent is recreated. Quoting from this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/region),

> “Once an agent is created, its location cannot change. In order to change an agent's location, you must export and restore to a new agent with a different location.”

- You might have missed to specify a region with the API request. For REST calls, you must do both the following:

  - Provide the region ID for the location URL path parameter.
  - Use [region-id]-dialogflow.googleapis.com for the hostname.

  For example:

```
  us-central1-dialogflow.googleapis.com/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/locations/us-central1/agents/{AGENT_ID}
```

Comment: Hi @Morten, If you find my answer helpful for your question, please consider to accept/upvote it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).